# Cakephp Ajax post data not working in set method

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am trying sent one data from one view to another controller and set the data for another view. Here is ajax code working fine

```
$.ajax({  
         url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'exchange_process'));?>",  
                      type: "POST",  
                      data: {"point_origin": point_origin },  
                      success: function(){              
                             alert("success");  
                 }
        });
```

In controller I have received this data by bellow code

```
public function exchange_process()
    {
        if($this->request->is(array('post', 'ajax'))) {
            $point_origin=$_POST['point_origin'];
        }

        $this->set("pointorg",$point_origin);
    }
```

In another view I have tried

```
<?php echo $pointorg ?>
```

It's not working.

if I try

```
 public function exchange_process()
        {
            if($this->request->is(array('post', 'ajax'))) {
               // $point_origin=$_POST['point_origin'];
            }

            $point_origin=123;
            $this->set("pointorg",$point_origin);
        }
```

It's working,but if I try

```
 public function exchange_process()
            {
                if($this->request->is(array('post', 'ajax'))) {
                   // $point_origin=$_POST['point_origin'];
                   $point_origin=123;
                }


                $this->set("pointorg",$point_origin);
            }
```

It's not working.

Comment: my first guess according to your examples given would be that the if condition is never true and therefore the pointorg variable is never set

Comment: Have you tried debugging inside the request type check?

Also it makes more sense to use $this->request->data to retrieve data from the request.

Comment: For retrieve data may you provide me an example please ?

Comment: user firebug for ajax request. it will tell you the response

Answer (score 0):

change your if clause to:

```
if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('ajax')) {
```

and it should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 2.3 doesnot support array of type headers, please check

```
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-4-migration-guide.html#cakerequest
```

you will need to check individually or use Ajax only if request is to be sent using Ajax only.

Comment: Here problem only in condition variable inside condition not working, variable outside of condition working.I have given an example in my question.

Comment: yes problem is there that it does not support array in cakephp 2.3 but it supports in cakephp 2.6 In cake 2.3 it will always respond a false.